# How to generate new log file daily using SLF4j

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I am using SLF4j  Logging component in my project , I am required to create new file everyday and write logs to that , can we configure logback.xml to do same.

Comment: You need a RollingFileAppender. You can google it.

Comment: Also refer to this: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender